Why are straight-in approaches dangerous at uncontrolled airfields?
Why are straight-in approaches ill-advised at uncontrolled airfields? My understanding is that the recommendation is to do a standard overhead join where possible, if there is no radio service.
But at an airfield I fly at, a straight in, long final feels safer because:

I can see straight ahead of me with a wide view, I would be able to see if someone was either ahead of me or turning base / final
Overhead joins add the risk of not seeing someone below you when descending, coming straight in mitigates that, especially if you come in slightly low

Interested in what I may be missing here.

This is very UK specific. I can see this making no sense at all to Americans, for example.

@Jamiec are overhead joins UK specific?

Im not 100% sure, I have flown a fair amount in the US and it wasn't a thing there. My flying in mainland europe is fairly limited, so I can't be sure.

Straight in approaches happen in the US, and cause accidents:  https://data.ntsb.gov/carol-repgen/api/Aviation/ReportMain/GenerateNewestReport/105763/pdf

@AShelly arguably, that crash was ADSB-related. We'll never know for sure, but reading about the 152's behavior it's consistent with a panicked response stemming from an ADSB traffic alert (“Going around, because you are coming at me pretty quick man.”). So the straight-in might not have been the causal factor, it might have been the (mis)reliance on an ATC airspace management tool for collision avoidance.


Why are straight in approaches dangerous at uncontrolled airfields?

They're not, inherently. Everyone doing their own thing instead of following convention might be, though!

The CAA safety sense leaflet on "strip flying" feels relevant to your question, and has this to say (Emphasis theirs!):

If cloud base and airspace
permit, an ‘overhead join’
will allow you to observe
the windsock and any
obstructions on the strip.
Be alert for wildlife or livestock.
Keep circuits compact and avoid
overflying any noise sensitive
areas.
Even if the strip seems quiet,
be alert for other aircraft. It
is not unknown for passing
aircraft to use strips for practice
forced landings or even conduct
ad hoc ‘beat-ups’.

If you're joining on a 4+ mile final, spotting a couple of sheep or pedestrians/dogwalkers is difficult.
The main reason usually cited is spotting the windsock, but if you're 100% sure of the wind direction at ground level, this seems less of an issue.
The Skyway code also has this to say:

The ‘overhead’ join is the recommended
joining procedure for uncontrolled aerodromes.
It allows you to observe traffic in the circuit
prior to entry.

While I don't disagree that you might have better visibility coming in long final, if everyone follows the same procedure, then everyone else knows what to expect.

I think one of the big problems people have with someone flying a straight-in approach is that they often ignore the traffic in the pattern and just barge in with a "I'm on final, get put of my way." attitude.

In the US, FAA AC 90-66C speaks to this topic, just FYI.

@AeroAndy Oh interesting, I didnt think you guys had an concept whatsoever of an "overhead join". Every bit of flying ive done in the US has been join 45 to downwind.

In addition to being a way to observe the runway conditions, doing an overhead join ensures that the aircraft has some altitude margin while being just above the runway: this way, if things go wrong, a shortened approach is always a solution.
This may not be considered for controlled airfields, where traffic separation is a priority.
This is the recommended approach for gliders, where the pilot really needs to check for local winds; but is also useful for motored aircraft, where an engine failure is always possible and would be a bad situation when engaged in a long final already on 3 degrees path.

A friend of mine narrowly avoided a midair collision right after takeoff when another small plane was executing a straight-in final on the same runway. After landing, he never flew again.
Flying a pattern approach forces the pilot to identify and join into existing traffic which requires radio communication and situational awareness.
